# How to pass file array data by ajax and how to receive data in php file?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, json

How to pass file array data by ajax and how to receive data by php file?

Please send me the example code of this issue. I have got data by FormData($(this)[0]) but fetch some problem. First time not got any data from text area (refresh page i.e. after page load first time). But second time I got (not refresh page).

I have made some code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <script>        
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("form#formD").submit(function(event){             
                event.preventDefault();
                var name = $("#name").val();
                var text = $("#text").val();
                var upload = $("#upload").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "test.php",
                    data: {"name" : name, "" : text, "upload" : JSON.stringify(upload)},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,                     
                    beforeSend: function(){ $("#send").val('Sending...'); },
                    success: function( html ){  
                        alert( html );
                        $("#send").val('send');
                    }
                });             
                return false;
            });
        });     
    </script>
    <form id="formD" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <label>File name</label>: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required /><br /><br />
    <label>File Description</label>: <textarea id="text"></textarea><br /><br />
    <label>Select File</label>: <input type="file" name="upload[]" id="upload[]" required /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="send" id="send" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the PHP file, you would use the super global $_POST.
This is an array of all data passed via the POST command.

To iterate through it, would be like

```
foreach($_POST as $sPostKey => $sPostValue) {

    // do stuff here

}
```

Remember to use json_decode to turn that JSON into something usable within PHP.

Comment: Data can't be send to php.

Comment: What do you mean by that?